# Angular CDK's OverlayModule, cdk-overlay-pane will not set position to absolute?

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using Overlay Module of Angular's CDK. And I just cannot find the way to add position: absolute to the overlay?  The module will receive a `top` and a `left` position that matches the connected element position but the overlay will not receive `position: absolute`.  I'm unable to add position absolute due to ViewEncapsulation.  and I'm really struggling to find a solution.

**Question:**
How can I use `cdkOverlayOrigin` and `cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin`

Module:

```js
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OverlayModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
})
export class MenuModule {
}
```

Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './menu.component.scss' ],
})
export class MenuComponent {
}
```

Template:

```html
 <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 30%">
  <h1 cdkOverlayOrigin
      #checkListTrigger="cdkOverlayOrigin"
      (click)="checkListOpen = !checkListOpen"
      style="background: blue">Overlay Origin</h1>
  <ng-template
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="checkListTrigger"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="checkListOpen">

    <ng-container>
      <p>Why you no positioned on h1 element</p>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-template>
</div>
```

See how it's off center
[image]

If I add position: absolute it now works as intended?
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `OverlayModule` instead of the Angular - Material `mat-dialog`? https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview (This being the standard for usking `cdk` items in Angular)

Comment: Because I'm trying to make a popover overlay/tooltip and not a dialog box persay

Comment: The dialog is supposed to be the all-browser standard for anything that requires more than a span for rendering in DOM. If all you want is text, then Material provides the `tooltip`. You can position the dialog to an element in the view w/ customization, and you can manipulate it many more ways (though the defaults are prettys tandard)

Comment: It isn't a tooltip either.  https://joejordanbrown.github.io/material2-popover-demo/popover is something more that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [API documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayConfig). You can specify a panel class for the overlay pane.

Here's some code:

```ts
const overlay = overlay.create({
    panelClass: 'pos-absolute'
});
```

```css
.pos-absolute {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: HI Edric, I got the same example Matthew, but can't figure out how do assign the overlay to the same code ? I created a git repo https://github.com/frontruk/overaly-module/blob/master/src/app/modules/overlay-dialog/overlay-dialog.component.ts , if you could help that would be awesome

Answer (score 22):

The absolute positioning of the generated overlay container is defined in the `.cdk-overlay-pane` class, which is part of the angular material theme. You might have forgot to include a theme?

If so, add the following line to your style.css file (assuming you use an Angular CLI project).
`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Comment: this answer helped me to focus on core problem: missing theme imports in styles.scss.
I added 

`@use '@angular/material' as mat; //use tilda '~@angular/..... for angular <13`
and
`@import '@angular/material/theming'; //use tilda '~@angular/..... for angular <13`
and
`@include mat.core();`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by niio's comment, I figured out I had not included the `core` part of angular material theming (Angular 15):

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();
```

That put the select panel back to place.